# How to configure log4j for Hibernate logging?

Tags: hibernate, logging, configuration, log4j

I have trouble with a special Hibernate 5 problem, but cannot enable DEBUG-Logging to get more information about the real problem.

From the Hibernate 5 Documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-logging

> In order to setup logging you will need slf4j-api.jar in your classpath together with the jar file for your preferred binding - slf4j-log4j12.jar in the case of Log4J

In my project classpath are:

```
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.0.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
log4j-api-2.0.jar
org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar
```

My log4j.properties is very simple

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.org.hibernate=ALL
```

I tried also: log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ALL, log4j.category.org.hibernate=TRACE, log4j.category.org.hibernate=DEBUG.

The log4j.properties is directly in the classpath folder.

BUT... I cannot see any Hibernate-logs.

EDIT:

One more detail: the first lines(log4j.appender) in the log4j.properties seem to work correctly